# Contest questions today (3/14)

Tags: discussion, contests

Pizza Hut is having a [contest](http://blog.pizzahut.com/flavor-news/national-pi-day-math-contest-problems-are-here-2/) today (March 14). The questions are in the link above. I thought I'd make this known here in case anyone posts them on the main site.

Of course, such posts should not be answered and flagged (?).

Comment: Thanks for the info. That "contest" seems pretty marginal to me though; it seems more like a promotion than an actual contest. Plus there is plenty of discussion going on on that site itself  so I really do not see much risk. If such a question turns up, without mentioning the context it can be useful to add it. But any other form of non-standard moderation against it seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Whenever a math-contest has a strong commercial side, my normally uncompromising desire to defend the integrity of the said contest appears to go wayyyy down.

Comment: Independent of whether the contest is commercial or not, it seems to have a picture of the Altas, if the prize is that book. I'll be interested ;-p

Comment: I heard that the prize is free pizza for 3.14 years.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't enter any mathematical competition involving the gentleman in [that picture](http://blog.pizzahut.com/flavor-news/national-pi-day-math-contest-problems-are-here-2/), because I know I'd be bound to lose. $\ddot{\smile}$.